# WebClient difference between WebClient.Builder and WebClient.create

Tags: java, spring-webclient

I have taken over some code, whee they are using
WebClient.builder().build() to create the WebClient. Rather than WebClient.create() The problem is I am not sure how to use the WebClient created by WebClient.builder().build().
I have the following code

```
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
```

```
Boolean flag = webClient.get()
                .uri(url)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Boolean.class)
                .block();
```

This will work if I use WebClient.create()

But using build I get the following exception, so there has to be some functionality I am missing to get WebClient from build working.

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$ServiceUnavailable: 503 Service Unavailable from UNKNOWN 
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:207)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ 503 from GET http://localhost:8084/throttling?paramUrl=https://playwright.dev/ [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultClientResponse.lambda$createException$1(DefaultClientResponse.java:206)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:96)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:330)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1782)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:152)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust$WeakScalarSubscription.request(FluxJust.java:101)
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?